# if $(document).not-ready()? How can I check if the page is still loading with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I want to call a function only if the document is still loading.. how can I?

Comment: My question when I see these questions is, why don't you just put your code inside `$().ready()`. I suppose that is because you want to do something while the document is not ready?

Answer (score 8):

You could check [`document.readyState`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SVEA_enGB358GB358&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=document.readystate+mdc) or use a simple variable in the global scope:

```
var ready = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    ready = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a function normally in JavaScript and overwrite it within `jQuery.ready`:

```
function foo() {
    // …
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    foo = function() {};
});
foo();
```

Now if `foo` calls itself recursively, it will stop when `foo` is redefined when the document is ready.

Comment: Why not use a simple variable instead of a recursive method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the very useful jQuery deferred object to check if the document has/hasn't loaded yet:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

http://eng.wealthfront.com/2012/12/jquerydeferred-is-most-important-client.html

E.g.

```
(function($) {    
    var jqReady = $.Deferred();
    // Bind doc ready to my deferred object
    $(document).bind("ready", jqReady.resolve);

    // Check to see is doc is ready
    if(jqReady.state() !== 'resolved'){
        alert('Doc is not ready');
    }

    $.when(jqReady).then(function () {
        // Code here will run when doc is ready/state === 'resolved'
        alert('Doc is ready');
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinfoley/um6sB/)

Comment: In Chrome 65, the page loads behind the first alert and never displays `alert('Doc is ready')`

Comment: @Dshiz I just tested the JSFiddle link in Chrome 65 and it worked fine?

Comment: @Dshiz must be something else wrong then. Happy to help if you setup a fiddle with an ex.