# Process socket.io messages from the server before DOM loads or make DOM wait until all messages are processed?

Tags: jquery, node.js, dom, socket.io

I have been looking into ways I can make the browser DOM wait to load until it has received and processed all socket.io messages from the server.

Let's say I have the server emitting to the browser each cat jpeg URL from an array of 50 where the target images are of varying sizes:

```
catimgurl.forEach(function(cat) {
    socket.emit('cat', cat)
}
```

I have the browser waiting for these URLs on the client side to process the image URLs and displaying them in `<img>` tags. But I don't want the page to display until all images are finished downloading into browser cache then ready for rendering once DOM is ready.

```
$(document).NOTready({
    socket.on('cat', function(catimgurl){
        $("<img src='"+catimgurl+"'/>").appendTo("body")
    })
})
```

Now that all cat images have been received and cached by the browser, the DOM can load and show the images.

I was looking at the answer from this stack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911598/1551027, but with this code it alerts while the document is not loaded and never alerts when has finished loading. So I don't think I can use it.

I also wonder if I need to start looking into server side rendering with something like angular, react or vue.

Any direction / insight is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd suggest you send one initial message to the client that sends an array of URLs:

```
// send initial array of image URLs to the client all at once
socket.emit('catInitial', catimgurl);
```

Then second, in the client, you can set up the page content so that it is initially hidden inside a container div with a CSS rule like this:

```
#pageContainer {display: none;}
```

And then after you receive and process the `catInitial` message, you can show the content.

```
// listen for initial image array message
socket.on('catInitial', function(catImgArray) {
   // make sure document is loaded before trying to insert the images
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // insert all the images
       catImgArray.forEach(function(catimgurl) {
           $("<img src='"+catimgurl+"'/>").appendTo("#pageContainer");
       });
       // now show the page content here by reversing the default CSS setting
       $("#pageContainer").show();
   });
});
```

You can even get a bit fancier and show some initial "page loading..." message initially and then after receiving the image content, you hide the "page loading ..." content and show the regular page content.

Comment: I've thought about this notion quite a bit. The problem I've been runing into (although this is probably because I'm not sending an array) is that each image loads at different times because of its size in bytes, network conditions, etc. Most of the time the delay is caused by CORS errors, which I created a handler for, but it changes the order of the images. It seems like this approach will solve that problem?

Comment: @Dshiz - If you want to wait for the images themselves to load into the browser before you display anything, then you will need a little more code to implement that.   To do that, you will need `onload` handlers for each of the image tags you insert and not show the container until all of those have fired.  If you need help with implementing that, let me know.  FYI, `<img>` URLs are not subject to CORS restrictions so I'm not sure what that part of your comment means.

Comment: I've been meaning to comment, but I'm working on rewriting everything. To answer your question about CORS, I'm receiving 403 forbidden responses from some of the remote image URLs. It may not be CORS, but it sure looked like it to me.. I may not have these issues after my rewrite...

Comment: @Dshiz - 403 is supposed to mean that the server understood your request, but decided you don't have access to that resource.  Since CORS is enforced in the browser (not on the server), it would be the browser, not the server that would decide on a CORS error.  I don't think that 403 error code is caused by CORs.